# Azure.Data.Tables C# SDK query Timestamp returning zero results

Tags: c#, azure

I have an Azure CosmosDB table, and when I query it using Azure.Data.Tables C# SDK with a filter on Timestamp, it returns zero columns. When I remove the filter, it applies the remaining query successfully.

For example, the filter below is used:

```
Timestamp ge datetime'2022-11-04T22:24:14.851Z'
```

When I apply the identical filter on the Azure Portal, the query behaves as expected, and filters the rows based on the Timestamp property.

I am expecting rows to be returned because there are rows that satisfy this filter (they were added after this date).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a feature of the Azure.Data.Tables SDK:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/32468

Answer (score 0):

Using below query, you can filter results based on time stamp.

```
"SELECT * FROM c WHERE (c[\"ShipDate\"] >= \"2014-09-30T23:14:25.7251173Z\")"
```

Steps I have followed to get data from cosmos db based on timestamp are,

1. Created cosmos db in Azure.
2. Created a C# console app and added below code,

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq;
// </using_directives>

// <endpoint_key> 
// New instance of CosmosClient class using an endpoint and key string
var Endpoint = "<cosmos db url>";
var Key = "<yourkey>";
CosmosClient cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(Endpoint, Key);// </endpoint_key>

// <create_database>
// New instance of Database class referencing the server-side database
Database database = await cosmosClient.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(
    id: "adventureworks"
);
// </create_database>

// <create_container>
// New instance of Container class referencing the server-side container
Container container = await database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(
    id: "products",
    partitionKeyPath: "/category",
    throughput: 400
);
// </create_container>

// <create_items> 
// Create new items and add to container
Product firstNewItem = new(
    id: "68719518388",
    category: "gear-surf-surfboards",
    name: "Sunnox Surfboard",
    quantity: 8,
    sale: true,
    ShipDate: DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-14)
);

Product secondNewitem = new(
    id: "68719518398",
    category: "gear-surf-surfboards",
    name: "Noosa Surfboard",
    quantity: 15,
    sale: false,
    ShipDate: DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-10)
);

await container.CreateItemAsync<Product>(
    item: firstNewItem,
    partitionKey: new PartitionKey("gear-surf-surfboards")
);

await container.CreateItemAsync<Product>(
    item: secondNewitem,
    partitionKey: new PartitionKey("gear-surf-surfboards")
);
// </create_items> 

// <query_items_sql>
// Query multiple items from container
using FeedIterator<Product> feed = container.GetItemQueryIterator<Product>(
    queryText: "SELECT * FROM c WHERE (c[\"ShipDate\"] >= \"2014-09-30T23:14:25.7251173Z\")"
);

// Iterate query result pages
while (feed.HasMoreResults)
{
    FeedResponse<Product> response = await feed.ReadNextAsync();

    // Iterate query results
    foreach (Product item in response)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Found item:\t{item.name}");
    }
}
```

3. Added one more class with name Product.cs and added below code,

```
 class Product
{
    public string id;
    public string category;
    public string name;
    public int quantity;
    public bool sale;
    public DateTime ShipDate;

    public Product(string id, string category, string name, int quantity, bool sale,DateTime ShipDate)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.category = category;
        this.name = name;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.sale = sale;
        this.ShipDate = ShipDate;

    }   
}
```

4. Able to get rows based on timestamp filter condition from cosmos db.

[image]
Reference [link](https://github.com/azure-samples/cosmos-db-nosql-dotnet-samples/blob/main/300-query-items/Program.cs#L64-L80)